# My function to merge two linked lists is not working properly

Tags: c, merge, linked-list

I'm supposed to make a function that will merge two sorted singly linked lists.

The user inputs two sets of numbers in the console, for example: `5 3 1 0`, which make a linked list, 0 signifies the end of that input and is not a part of that list. Then the lists are sorted, from the smallest to the largest value. After the sorting, elements of the lists are supposed to be added into a new list, one by one. At the end, the newly created list should be printed.

I've tried with a lot of different methods, but the one I liked the most was to have two different pointers to the heads, so p would be a pointer for head1 and q would be a pointer for head2. I start with whichever head value is smaller and move the pointer of that head to the next element. Then I remember that head with the node I'm going to return at the end, and move onto the while loop, where it goes from one list to another.

[image]

Okay, I use S to add the elements to my new list, first I start from the lower number between thew two lists, which is in this case 1 and the first list, as soon as I give S its value, I also move pointer p0 to the next element, so now its pointing to 3 (p1). Then I make that S the head of my new list and move onto the while loop. In while loop I check if the last element that was added to my new list was from the first or the second list, depending on the result, let's just say the last element was from the first list (number 1), we move onto the second list. I make S point to q1, q then points to the next element of the second list (q2) and the while loop starts again. The process repeats itself until one of the two pointers is NULL. After the while loop, I have two if statements (one for each pointers in case they point to NULL) where I return the other pointer. Hopefully now it's a bit more clear.

```
typedef struct Element Element;

struct Element {
    int data;
    Element *next;
};

Element *addNew(int data) {
    Element *newN = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element));

    newN->data = data;
    newN->next = NULL;

    return newN;
}

Element *add_on_beginning(Element *head, Element *newN) {
    newN->next = head;

    return newN;
}

Element *add_on_end(Element *head, Element *newN) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return newN;
    }

    Element *temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = newN;

    return head;
}

void swap(Element *a, Element *b) {
    int tempV;

    tempV = a->data;
    a->data = b->data;
    b->data = tempV;
}

void sortList(Element *head) {
    Element *temp;
    int swapped;

    do {
        swapped = 0;

        temp = head;

        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            if (temp->data > temp->next->data) {
                swap(temp, temp->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    } while(swapped);
}

Element *merge(Element *head1, Element *head2, Element *newHead) {
    Element *p = head1;
    Element *q = head2;
    Element *sort = NULL;

    if (p == NULL) {
        return q;
    }
    if (q == NULL) {
        return p;
    }

    if (p != NULL && q != NULL) {
        if (p->data <= q->data) {
            sort = p;
            p = sort->next;
        } else {
            sort = q;
            q = sort->next;
        }
    }

    newHead = sort;

    while (p != NULL && q != NULL) {
        if (sort->next == p->next) {
            sort->next = q;
            sort = q;
            q = sort->next;
        } else {
            sort->next = p;
            sort = p;
            p = sort->next;
        }
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        sort->next = q;
    }
    if (q == NULL) {
        sort->next = p;
    }

    return newHead;
}

void printElement(Element *element) {
    printf("%d ", element->data);
}

void printList(Element *head) {
    Element *temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printElement(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    Element *head = NULL;
    Element *head2 = NULL;
    Element *head3 = NULL;

    char t;
    int i;
    char p;
    int j;

    printf("Input the first set of numbers: \n");

    while (t != '\n') {
        scanf("%d%c", &i, &t);

        if (i == 0) {
            break;
        }

        head = add_on_end(head, addNew(i));
    }

    printf("Input the second set of numbers: \n");

    while (p != '\n') {
        scanf("%d%c", &j, &p);

        if (j == 0) {
            break;
        }

        head2 = add_on_end(head2, addNew(j));
    }

    sortList(head);
    sortList(head2);

    head3 = merge(head, head2, head3);

    printList(head3);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having is with merging, it prints out those two lists sorted but not merged with one and other, instead its the first list and right after the second.

So for example:

INPUT:

```
2 6 4 8 1 
7 9 2 3 5
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 4 6 8 2 3 5 7 9
```

It should be:

**INPUT**:

```
2 6 4 8 1
7 9 2 3 5
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: The answer to most problems with pointer constructs is "Take a pen and paper and extremely carefully play your own code." Please report from that activity, i.e. demonstrate that you did that kind of analysis.

Comment: I did, to be honest, multiple times. Everything looked right.

Comment: Then do some box-and-arrow ascii art of what you think how the pointers of your lists develop while executing your program. Maybe use smaller input.

Comment: I just edited my post, hopefully it will be a bit more understandable.

Comment: Using a pointer to pointer is often a solution . [and the`merge()` function does not need the 3rd argument]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge` function is too complicated:

- the test `if (p != NULL && q != NULL)` is redundant
- in the `while` loop you do not test the node values, which explains why `merge` fails.
- the third argument `newHead` is useless.

Here is a modified version:

```c
Element *merge(Element *p, Element *q) {
    Element *newHead = NULL;
    Element *sort = NULL;

    if (p == NULL) {
        return q;
    }
    if (q == NULL) {
        return p;
    }

    if (p->data <= q->data) {
        newHead = sort = p;
        p = p->next;
    } else {
        newHead = sort = q;
        q = q->next;
    }

    while (p != NULL && q != NULL) {
        if (p->data <= q->data) {
            sort = sort->next = p;
            p = p->next;
        } else {
            sort = sort->next = q;
            q = q->next;
        }
    }
    if (p == NULL) {
        sort->next = q;
    }
    if (q == NULL) {
        sort->next = p;
    }
    return newHead;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the *added* complexity in OP's code is caused by the need to handle the edge-cases(finding the address of the new head) Edge cases can sometimes be avoided.

Trivial solution using a pointer-to-pointer:

---

```
struct thing{
        struct thing *next;
        int value;
        };

struct thing *merge(struct thing *one, struct thing *two)
{
struct thing *result;
struct thing **pp; // will always point to the _pointer_ that will be assigned the next node.

result=NULL;
for(pp = &result; one && two; pp = &(*pp)->next) {
        if(one->value <= two->value) {
                *pp = one; one = one->next;
                }
        else    {
                *pp = two; two = two->next;
                }
        }

        // When we get here,  one and/or two will be NULL
*pp = (one) ? one : two;

return result;
}
```

---

The same logic, but with an extra dereference instead of the pointer-to-pointer:

---

```
struct thing *merge2(struct thing *one, struct thing *two)
{
struct thing dummy;
struct thing *last;

dummy.next=NULL;
for(last = &dummy; one && two; last = last->next) {
        if(one->value <= two->value) {
                last->next = one; one = one->next;
                }
        else    {
                last->next = two; two = two->next;
                }
        }

last->next = (one) ? one : two;

return dummy.next;
}
```

---

Now, the fun fact is,that `cc -Wall -omit-frame-pointer -O3 -S llist23.c` generates **exactly the same** code for these two functions.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, the only problem that I have is we have not covered double pointers in our classes yet, so that answer would not be accepted by my teacher. That is the reason I've been trying to do this without them.

Comment: It is only here to show the relative simplicity that can be obtained by `**pp` :the program doesn't need to remember *where* to assign to. (but:you could enumerate that into a separate variable)